# FZ grade and PhD application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, canada

I am graduate of Toronto University. In my master program, I, unfortunately, fail an elective course. I took an extra course to offset the credit and I pass.My overall grade is A- (except for the FZ one!).

I am intending to apply for a PhD. However, my transcript has an FZ which may be will interfere with the application procedure since UofT is very competitive Uni.

Can anyone please suggest me if it would be a good plan to retake the course (fail course)? Suppose I got a good grade, what would be the improvement?
or, any other way I can impress the admission authority.

NB. Other than this FZ (I call it as a disaster in my academic career), I have a good academic record.

Thank you in advance for your time and be with my worries.

A person with a passion for research!

Comment: Can you explain what an FZ is?

Comment: Ask UofT about the replacement grade for one, and ask the place where you apply for the PhD...